# Angularizing JustGage.js not functioning as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to incorporate the following library into angular.

http://justgage.com/

The directive is as below:

```
app.directive('playerScoreGauge', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      info: '='
    },
    template: '<div id="{{info.id}}"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var g = new JustGage({
        id: scope.info.id,
        value: scope.info.score,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: scope.info.name
      });



    }
  };

});
```

However, for some reason the directive is not binding to the JustGage object.

Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hkWOnelZlguYUkUDvSuI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the directive's link function runs, the `id` attribute's value has not yet been interpolated, and `JustGage` fails to find it.

Create your `JustGage` object inside `$timeout` - this would put it at the end of the digest queue:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   $timeout(function(){
      var g = new JustGage({
        id: scope.info.id,
        value: scope.info.score,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: scope.info.name
      });
   });
}
```

(Don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your directive)